# Using @ to denote responsibility

Tags: icons, roles

Would it be easily recognized if we used @john.smith at the beginning of the task description be used to denote "the individual responsible for the task"? Like in:

`[@John.Smith] Do the paperwork`

Or would that normally be read as some kind of reply?

Comment: It's no longer just an email thing, pretty much everyone (espcially if it's in a working environment) will understand it means "to <name>". Slack and Jira for example use it.

Comment: Twitter, for one, uses that pattern to direct messages at people, so without knowing any context of where this appears, it seems more like just a message for someone rather than designating accountability.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the limited context of your application, I would expect the `@John.Smith` tag to work as you'd want it to.

The @ "tag" is used to call attention to the user in question; replies are obviously a common use of it. Calling attention to a user in context of a task conveys responsibility or response.

Alternatively, you could use an "Assignee" field (assuming your task UI is a form):

> **Assignee**
>
> `John Smith`